# vue 3 script setup onBeforeMount is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Hello today i move to vue 3 with script setup.

I try use onBeforeMount for load external data (async await).

but receive error:
"onBeforeMount is not defined"

I going to documentation and saw that onBeforeMount should work! what is problem ?
[image]

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity';
import axios from 'axios';

var data = ref(null);

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    data.value = await axios.get("url");
})
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your code ;).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you've missed to import it from vue :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref} from '@vue/reactivity';

import {onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios';

var data = ref(null);

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    data.value = await axios.get("url");
})
</script>
```

Comment: oh.... stupid ide always all auto importing but now... thx its work. Right import is "from '@vue/runtime-core';"

Comment: just import all the hooks and reactivity properties from 'vue'